# Weird error that comes up during python program run

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, runtime-error, turtle-graphics

Whenever I run my program I get this error. Do you know what this means?
This happens when the

```
turtle.clear()
```

function is called

```
File "C:\Python32\lib\turtle.py", line 2642, in clear
    self._clear()
File "C:\Python32\lib\turtle.py", line 2621, in _clear
self.currentLineItem = self.screen._createline()
File "C:\Python32\lib\turtle.py", line 528, in _createline
capstyle = TK.ROUND)
File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2185, in create_line
return self._create('line', args, kw)
File "C:\Python32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2173, in _create
*(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'None'
```

Comment: whatever string you're trying to convert to a int, does not contain a integer, but the text 'None'. If you need more help to fix it, post the code where this errors happens.

Comment: Actually the `turtle` module is distributed with Python, it is often used in tutorials and sorts because it can be used to easily demonstrate various programming concepts. And the call to `clear` is not wrong. Do you always get that error when calling clear? What is the simplest code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Please, post some relevant code, that raises that exc.

Comment: This might possibly be related to https://bugs.python.org/issue33257, especially if the error is intermittent.  Some code and an answer to the 'always?' question would be helpful.